# Sort a list of tuples by their second elements

Tags: sorting, haskell, tuples

I want to sort a list of tuples by their second elements.

Example input:

```
[("Bob",3),("Terry",1)]
```

Example output:

```
[("Terry",1)("Bob",3)]
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should add the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 21):

Another cool trick is to use `on` from Data.Function:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

sortBy (compare `on` snd) [...]
```

Not much different than `comparing` but a nice trick from time to time.

Comment: `on` has some nice tricks. I occasionally find `equating = on (==)` to be useful. (`comparing = on compare`)

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy) and [`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v%3acomparing):

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
comparing :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
```

In this case, we want to compare by the second element. You can use `comparing snd` to get a function that can compare two tuples by their second element.

Comment: If i wanted to define my own sorting function to call from anywhere then how exactly can I do this? I may need to use this more than once

Comment: In other words I wanted to define my own sorting function that takes a lits of tuples sorts it based on its second element and then returns that same sorted list of tuples.

Comment: @user1214840 Same as any other definition: `myFancySort = {- implementation using ehird's hints here -}`

Answer (score 2):

Consider a "regular" sort

```
sort xs = ... a < b ...
```

Such sorts must make use of `compare`, or its friends such as `<`. So if you have implemented such a thing already, then instead of just `compare a b` or `a < b`, you can instead do `compare (snd a) (snd b)` or `snd a < snd b`.

```
sort xs = ... snd a < snd b ...
```

Of course if you get smart, you'll abstract out the "accessor", and make it an additional input to the sorting function:

```
sortComparingOn f xs = ... f a < f b ...
```

You might even abstract out the comparator altogether:

```
sortBy cmp xs = ... a `cmp` b ...
```

`sortBy` is provided in Data.List, as ehird mentioned.