# Sort a list of tuples by 2nd tuple element

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort a list of tuples by their second elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319133/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-their-second-elements)

Hey there i have a list of tuples that looks like this

```
[("x", [1,2,3]), ("y", [1,2]), ("z", [1,2,3,4])]
```

i want to sort the list in increasing order according to the length of the integer list which is the 2nd element in the tuple, however my haskell is poor at best and i cannot figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the sorting problems could be solved with [`sortBy ::(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy) function. So the task is to generate ordering function which compares two elements based on length of second element of the tuple. `` compare `on` (length . snd) :: (a1, [a]) -> (a1, [a]) -> Ordering `` is what we actually need.

```
eblo> sortBy (compare `on` (length . snd)) [("x", [1,2,3]), ("y", [1,2]), ("z", [1,2,3,4])]
[("y",[1,2]),("x",[1,2,3]),("z",[1,2,3,4])]
```

Comment: You can't have markdown syntax *inside* code spans, but you can wrap an entire code span in a link.

Answer (score 12):

```
sortBy (comparing $ length . snd) [("x", [1,2,3]), ("y", [1,2]), ("z", [1,2,3,4])]
```

Comment: for reference (for other readers), `sortBy` is not in Prelude, but Data.List, while `comparing` is in Data.Ord